# Chrome not rendering multiple SVG

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

I have a page with two embedded SVG, you can see it here:

http://www.lemonskin.net/404

If you open it with any browser you'll see two rotating logos, one on the top bar and another one in the middle of the screen, inside the double 4 digits (sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links :|).

Well, in Chrome they both don't show:

[Chrome 49.0.2623.110 (64-bit) for OS X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58jqi.png)

The curious part is that, if you open another page, for example the root, then Chrome will render the first SVG (the logo on the bar).

Now, both SVG are different and have different ID. Also they follow different CSS.
Any idea?

Comment: remove the `<base>` tag.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: WOW, many thanks Robert! I'd like to give you some rep but I'm new on Stack Overflow and I've no idea how to do. :)